# Need help making this encrypter

Tags: python, encryption

Hi I have this encryter that Im tring to make at school GCSE level and I need help because i dont understand whats wrong with it at the moment im expecting a final number to pop up istead of an encrypted script but i got a string index error how do I fix this?

```
# This asks a user for an input of text integers etc
text = input('Enter A Word : ')
# Empty Value used to store the encrypted value
encrypt = ''
# Empty temp value replaced at every iteration of the wencryption process
temp = ''
# Empty temp value replaced at every iteration of the wencryption process
temp2 = ''

# key used to shift the letters
key = int(input('Enter your key (their will be more encryption) : '))

for i in range(0,len(text)):
    # Rearranges text in a caps switch
    if str.islower(text[i]):
        temp += str.upper(text[i])
    elif str.isupper(text[i]):
        temp += str.lower(text[i])
    else:
        temp += text[i]

for j in range(0, len(temp)):
    temp = str(ord(temp[j]))
    temp2 += temp + str(key)
    encrypt += temp2

print(encrypt)
```

Comment: Why are you trying to create your own encryption?  Is this part of some assignment?

Comment: Can you add the error traceback, so we can see where the error is happening?

Comment: `temp = str(ord(temp[i]))` That `i` should probably be a `j`.

Comment: thank you guys for support, this is an assignment the error traceback was     temp=str(ord(temp[j]))
IndexError: string index out of range

Comment: Hi there. I apologise for needing to roll back your question - let me explain why that was necessary. The point of Stack Overflow is to produce useful question and answer pages that might be useful to someone else. So, when you asked a question on Feb 28th, you were lucky enough to get an answer from  Mikael Brenner, within five minutes. That creates a useful question-and-answer pair. However, you then substantially modified your question, to the degree that Mikael's answer probably would no longer make any sense, which is not fair to them.

Comment: Thus, if you have a new (related) question, please ask a new question. Since you already have an answer to it, you can if you wish post that answer on your new question, to help future readers. I suggest two further things: (1) delete your answer here, since it is probably not an answer to the rolled-back question, and (2) when posting an answer, explain _how_ that answer helps. Your current answer does not do that - but you can edit it!

Comment: thank you @halfer for the suggestion. I will do this right away

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks guys for the support; I figured out how to solve this encryption algorithm. The answer will be posted below (PS you can obviously use this).
This Python script uses for and range functions to split the string into each individual character so then it can be rearranged.

First I do a simple cAPS sWITCH(unecessary for the meantime) so I can make my encrypter secure. Then I use the ord function to convert each character into its ascii equivalent then I use a simple cipher technique and ask for a simple integer key (such as 3 [Caesar] or 13 [ROT13]). Then the ascii value and the key is added so the ascii value changes accordingly.

Then we convert the ascii digit into a character using the chr function which is used to make ascii values into chr. When we have done that we use concatenation to join each letter to a final variable to later display on your screen!

```
enter code here

text = input('Enter A Word : ') ##This asks a user for an input of text integers etc
encrypt = '' ##Empty Value used to store the encrypted value
temp = '' ##Empty temp value replaced at every iteration of the encryption process
temp2 =0 ##Empty temp value replaced at every iteration of the encryption process
temp_val=0
temp_char=''

key=int(input('Enter your key (their will be more encryption) : '))##key used to shift the letters

for i in range(0,len(text)):
    ##Rearranges text in a caps switch
    if str.islower(text[i])==True:
        temp=temp+str.upper(text[i])
    elif str.isupper(text[i])==True:
        temp=temp+str.lower(text[i])
    else:
        temp=temp+text[i]
for j in range(0,len(temp)):
    temp_val=0
    temp2=0
    temp_val=ord(temp[j])
    temp2=temp2+temp_val+key
    temp_char=temp_char+chr(temp2)
    encrypt=temp_char
print(encrypt)
print(temp)
print(temp2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't really understand what was supposed to happen at `temp=str(ord(temp[i]))`.

This code generates a number:

```
text = input('Enter A Word : ') ##This asks a user for an input of text integers etc
encrypt = '' ##Empty Value used to store the encrypted value
temp = '' ##Empty temp value replaced at every iteration of the wencryption process
temp2 = '' ##Empty temp value replaced at every iteration of the wencryption process

key=int(input('Enter your key (their will be more encryption) : '))##key used to shift the letters


for i in range(0,len(text)):
    ##Rearranges text in a caps switch
    if str.islower(text[i])==True:
        temp=temp+str.upper(text[i])
    elif str.isupper(text[i])==True:
        temp=temp+str.lower(text[i])
    else:
        temp=temp+text[i]
for j in temp:
    temp=str(ord(j))
    temp2=temp2+temp+str(key)
    encrypt=encrypt+temp2
print(encrypt)
```

Comment: `ord()` converts the char at `temp[i]` into an ordinal number, and then back into a `str()` so they can concatenate the strings.